# Что означают данные строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я изучаю Python 3 по пособию и остановившись на теме, связанной со свойствами для атрибутов, не совсем могу понять философию некоторых строк. Вот они

> "У использования свойств вместо непосредственного доступа к атрибутам имеется ещё одно преимущество: если вы измените определение атрибута, вам нужно будет поправить только код внутри определения класса вместо того, чтобы править все вызовы."

В принципе, я понимаю, что"определение класса" это сам код внутри класса, но "определение атрибута" не такое ясное для меня понятие и о каких вызовах идёт речь. Буду благодарен, если кто-то покажет ситуацию на примерах простого кода.

Answer (score 1):

Речь идёт о том, что если вы решили переписать класс так, что структура его аттрибутов изменится, то вы можете просто поправить property так, чтобы оно корректно отдавало результат по старому.

Но если вы не используете property, то в этой ситуации вам придётся исправлять и весь внешний код, который раньше обращался напрямую к аттрибутам класса, а теперь уже не может этого сделать.